# Are categories meaningful when they're equally predictive?

Tags: categorical-data, unbalanced-classes

I have some categories in a fraud dataset I'm working on that are composed of 99% one category and 1% the other. On inspection these categories contain the exact same percentage of frauds ~1.4%, which is inline with my dataset's average.

If the categories present nearly the same information in terms of the target, are they meaningfully different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the dataset below. Let `y` be the fraud indicator and `x1`, `x2`, `x3` the other categories.

```
y   x1  x2  x3
Y   Y   N   N   
N   Y   N   N
N   Y   N   N
Y   N   Y   N
N   N   Y   N
N   N   Y   N
Y   N   N   Y
N   N   N   Y
N   N   N   Y
```

As you can see globally there is 30% of fraudulent cases, also per each level of the `xN` categories there are 30% of fraudulent cases. However, notice that for each `xN` category a *different* observation is fraudulent. So finding the fraudulent `x1` is different than finding it in `x2` or `x3`. They are definitely not the same, nonetheless that the probabilities are the same for them.

In this example, `y` is independent of `xN`s, so it doesn't really matter, but for a real dataset it can be the case that such variables have predictive power when taken together with the rest of the dataset. For example, let's say you are selling insurance and per premium vs non-premium customer categories and they have roughly the same % of fraud. If you had a way of predicting fraud in the premium category, it won't help for the non-premium category and the other way around. You would need both. If you ignored the categories, you wouldn't account for the different kinds of fraud in both groups.

Comment: To clarify, are they still likely to be meaningful? If there was a single column, would they still be meaningful? Or do the multiple columns make them meaningful?

Comment: I'll clarify in edit.

Comment: Not wanting to make this philosophical, but what is the meaning of "meaningful"? If I find that men and women are essentially equal on some measure, that doesn't make the categories meaningless. It just implies that they don't have predictive value for that specific purpose. In your case not finding any predictability is a disappointment, but it's a failure on a challenging problem.

Comment: @NickCox I suppose meaningful means "meaningfully different from the point of view of the problem I'm trying to solve".

Comment: Fair enough, but we don't have any information that you don't have. The same proportion is the same proportion.  The only thing I can suggest is looking in more detail at subsets of the data, depending on what other variables you have.